# Is there a more efficient way to compute positive modulo?

Tags: c++, modulo, performance

Modulo in C and C++ does not behave in a mathematically correct manner, as it returns a negative result when performing the modulo of a negative number. After doing some research, it seems the classic way of implementing a correctly behaving one is:

```
positive modulo(int i, int n)
{
   return ( ( (i % n) + n ) % n );
}
```

Considering modulo is computationally expensive, is there a more efficient way to compute positive modulo for any number (I already saw the solution for powers of 2, but I need something generic)?

Comment: Just `abs` the value first?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: That does the wrong thing.

Comment: Addition in C and C++ does not behave in a mathematically correct manner, as it returns a negative result when performing the addition of very large numbers. // sorry, couldn't resist. Most operations in programming are not mathematically correct.

Comment: @user2357112: "That does the wrong thing" : can you elaborate this ?

Comment: `positive_modulo(-1, 3)` should be 2, not 1.

Comment: On my environnment : for `i = 10` and `n = 3` `( (i % n) + n ) % n` gives `1`, but for `i = -10` and `n = 3` the result is `2`. Is that supposed to be correct ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, yes. `10 = 3 + 3 + 3 + 1`. `-10 = -3 -3 -3 -3 + 2`

Comment: The mathematical result of modulo should always be positive, and should be how much you need to add to the number to reach the closest multiple of n for the divisor d.

Comment: I had already read through the other post before asking this question , but it didn't have the answer I was looking for. It presented the classical solution, just not the most efficient one.

Comment: Mathematical modulo has the same sign as the divisor or zero (rounding towards negative infinity). C / C++ modulo has the same sign as the dividend or zero (rounding towards zero).

Comment: *Mathematically*, the modulo `a % b` is defined to be the remainder of the division `a / b`.  The common convention in mathematics is for `a / b` to be *euclidean division*, which results in a strictly positive remainder.  However, most programming languages, including C and C++, use *truncating division* for `a / b`; the issue isn’t really that modulus is defined incorrectly, rather it’s that a different definition of division is in use, which forces modulus to be defined in the way that it is.

Comment: @StephenCanon: It really is an incorrect definition, when it doesn't map integers into equivalence classes.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It's only an incorrect definition if you expect x % n --> y to be the standard mapping from Z into Z/nZ.  That's a perfectly nice definition, but it's not the definition of the % operator (which, in fairness, really should be called "remainder" to avoid this confusion).  But "modulus" is a heavily overloaded term; there's no point in pretending that it has only one meaning.

Answer (score 3):

This may be slower or faster, depending on the compiler, the optimization level and the architecture:

```
static inline int modulo(int i, int n) {
  const int k = i % n;
  return k < 0 ? k + n : k;
}
```

The reason why it can be slower is that the condition operation may introduce a branch, and sometimes branches are slow.

Comment: The branch is slow but most devices today that don't have hardware divisor are mostly embedded systems in which branch or not doesn't affect much performance since it doesn't have superscalar or some other features as well

Comment: On my system it compiles to 
        movl    %edi, %eax
        cltd
        idivl   %esi
        addl    %edx, %esi
        movl    %edx, %eax
        testl   %edx, %edx
        cmovs   %esi, %eax

Which doesn't have a branch, it instead uses a conditional move which should be fast.

Comment: The logic is equivalent to `return (i % n) + (i < 0) * n;`  , assuming `n>0`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: With modern compilers, `(i<0) * n` no longer is an optimization. On systems where that can be implemented branchless, the equivalent conditional code is also compiled without branches (see jcoder's example).

Comment: It's meant to be a clarification :) These days we trust the compiler to generate the best compiled code for simple arithmetic sequences.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in [pts's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22984056/995714) is probbaly the best solution. It *often* compiles to a branchless code, but even if there are slowdowns by the branch, it may possibly be faster than the division anyway. But in case you really need to avoid branching

```
inline int modulo(int i, int n)
{
    int k = i % n;
    int a = -(k < 0);  // assuming 2's complement
    // or int a = ((k < 0) << (INT_SIZE - 1)) >> (INT_SIZE - 1); if your system doesn't use 2's complement
    return k + n & a;
}
```

Comment: How will I be bale to know if 2's compliment is used ?

Comment: most modern systems use 2's complement

Comment: `a = -(k < 0);` works regardless of representation, it will set `a` to either `0` or `-1`. To make the code portable, change `n & a` to `n * -a`. Hopefully the compiler will generate optimal code in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The second modulo in your formula is necessary only to substract `n` again if the modulo was posivite in the first place. So it should be at least as performant to only *conditionally* add `n`:

```
   auto m = (i % n);
   return (m < 0) ? m+n : m;
```